Unable to change Astropy cache location
I'm running the latest version of Astropy in Python using a Mac. I'd like to change the directory where Astropy caches files.
I'm running:
astropy.config.set_temp_cache(path='/Users/josephprendergast/Documents/Temp/', delete=False)

I'm not getting an error but the directory is not being changed. Furthermore when I run:
astropy.config.get_cache_dir()

I get the default path and not my new path.
I tried the above and expected the cache directory to change

astropy.config.set_temp_cache() is meant to be used as a context manager, or as a decorator on functions. See the documentation here: https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.config.set_temp_cache.html
An example usage as a context manager with your snippet would be:
from astropy.config import set_temp_cache, get_cache_dir
with set_temp_cache(path='/Users/josephprendergast/Documents/Temp/', delete=False):
    # your code here
    print(get_cache_dir())

Outputs:
/Users/josephprendergast/Documents/Temp/astropy

